# Is the principal square root continuous on the set $\mathbb{C}-\{x+0i:x>0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that the principal square root, which maps $z=re^{i\varphi}$ to $\sqrt{r} e^{i\frac{\varphi}{2}}$ is continuous and holomorphic on the set $\mathbb{C}-\{x+0i:x\geq 0\}$. When trying to include a positive number, for example 1, you get a discontinuity, because $\sqrt{e^{i \varphi}}\to 1, \varphi\to 0,$ and $\sqrt{e^{i\varphi}}\to-1,\varphi\to 2\pi$. I have failed to use the same argument how show that $\sqrt{}$ isn't continuous at 0 when considering the set $\mathbb{C}-\{x+0i:x> 0\}$. So is $\sqrt{}$ continuous on the given set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One equivalent statement to the Riemann mapping theorem is that an open set $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ is simply connected if and only if every analytic nowhere zero function on $\Omega$ has an analytic square root on $\Omega$. I leave it to you to draw the appropriate conclusions for your specific question here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is continuous (or at least it can be continuously extended), since $\sqrt z\to0= \sqrt0$ as $z\to0$.